# Stokes' law for disks

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, viscosity

Stokes' law of viscous friction is famously applicable to spheres in (slow) motion within a fluid. If the object has radius $r$ and speed $v$, and the fluid has dynamic viscosity $\eta$, the dampening force will be

$$\mathbf F_f = -b\mathbf e_t $$
(where $\mathbf e_t$ is the unit tangential vector) with $b = 6\pi \eta rv$.

Now, what if the object is a disk of radius $r$ and thickness $h$ instead? (Supposing, e.g., that the disk's trajectory is always orthogonal to its circular surface.) How will the formula for $b$ change?

**EDIT:** This question is *not* a duplicate of the one posted in the comments, since as I have specified the object I am interested in is a finite-length cylinder immersed in a 3D fluid.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235126/

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for Stokes flow drag forces on a finite-length cylinder rather than the typical approximation that the cylinder is infinite (i.e., $h \rightarrow \infty$)?

Comment: The cylinder has finite length and finite radius.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminal velocity of a settling sphere in 2D vs 3D](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/354408/)